# 3rd Party Jar Exiting my Program?

Tags: java, swing, system.exit

Ok, so recently I made a program like snipping tool in java using swing that allows you to select an area of you screen and save it as an image to you computer.

Now, what I am trying to do is make a brand new project that uses the other program i made.

However, when the 3rd party jar is launched in my new app, it works fine, but when i close the 3rd party app it also closes my new app.  I do use system exit in the 3rd part app which I know is the reason it is closing everything.

Now my question is: is it wrong to use system exit for that reason?  Is there something I can do to prevent closing my new app without modifying the old one?

Or, could you give suggestions in the future instead of using system.exit because I still want the original one to be able to close properly, i just don't want my new one that uses the old jar to close as well.

I have tried disabling system exit in my new app which just creates more problems.

Comment: I think you may want to explore the ServiceLoader class a bit..
This way you create a "SnippingProvider"..

Comment: it is wrong to use system exit for that reason as well as other reasons. It shouldn't be used in any code that could be used as a library. And no, you can't really prevent it - you'll have to remove the system exit call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use System.exit();

> Is there something I can do to prevent closing my new app without modifying the old one?

use:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

if the frame is the only window open it will exit the JVM. If other Windows are open only the current Window is closed. The default close operation is used when you click on the "Close" button of the Window.

Better yet, don't use a JFrame as the Window for your tool. Instead you should use a JDialog.

Comment: And of course it won't close if the main of the original is still running, which is most important

Comment: If i were to modify the old app to only use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, it would not fully exit the program correct, just get rid of the window? EDIT: Nevermind, I see what you are saying, when i instantiate the 3rd party app, modify the JFrame to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE and then the original will still be EXIT_ON_CLOSE / System.exit().  Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, you can also use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE on your main JFrame as well and the JVM will dispose of the frame and then exit the JVM when all Threads have stopped running. Also, if you are creating the 3rd party app, it should not be a JFrame. It should be a JDialog and then it will be created as a child window of your JFrame since it is not a stand alone application.

Comment: Ok, so i just did a few changes in the 3rd party app and replaced EXIT_ON_CLOSE with DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE and replaced System.exit(0) with dispose(), and now it is working properly! Thank you for the help everyone!